# Assigning clicked element's ID as classname to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project but the code that I wrote is really wrong:

```
$('#lart').click(function(){
  $("#form3").addClass("lart");
});
$('#posht').click(function(){
  $("#form3").addClass("posht");
});
$('#majt').click(function(){
  $("#form3").addClass("majt");
});
$('#djatht').click(function(){
  $("#form3").addClass("djatht");
});
```

I think about making it with switch statement but I dont know how to make the variable for the cases. The above code doesnt work properly because when I click more options then it adds more classes and I don't want it to add more classes, just one of them (lart,posht,djatht,majt).

what if I want it to have two pairs like just to change the lart with posht and majt with djatht, by the way this is the meaning of the ids: lart=up posht=down majt=left djatht=right so if I click the up button then I click right the class up with stay its just going to add 1 more class called right, or left! or if I click the down button then I will can change the right or left but it will be (down and left/right or up and left/right) is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for a switch statement. Simply select all your elements, bind the event handler, and use the ID as the class:

```
$('#lart, #posht, #majt, #djatht').click(function(){
    $("#form3").prop('class', this.id);
});
```

---

If you want to be sure you're not removing any other classes, use this:

```
$('#lart, #posht, #majt, #djatht').click(function(){
    $("#form3").removeClass('lart posht majt djatht').addClass(this.id);
});
```

---

**Update:** solution to the problem posted in the comments (for easier understanding, I'll be using the English words for for directions):

```
var opposites = {
        up:     'down',
        down:   'up',
        right:  'left',
        left:   'right'
    };

$('#up, #right, #down, #left').click(function() {

    $("#form3").addClass(this.id).removeClass( opposites[this.id] );
});
```

Comment: This is indeed a concise approach. It has the potential to be a source of bugs, though, as it would be easy to at some point in the future add a class name to the form without realizing that it will disappear when one of these elements is clicked.

Comment: @davidchambers - True. Updated with a slightly different approach.

Comment: @JosephSilber what if I want it to have two pairs like just to change the lart with posht and majt with djatht, by the way this is the meaning of the ids: lart=up posht=down majt=left djatht=right so if I click the up button then I click right the class up with stay its just going to add 1 more class called right, or left! or if I click the down button then I will can change the right or left but it will be (down and left/right or up and left/right)

Answer (score 2):

updated: only appends one class at a time.

```
$("#lart,#posht,#majt,#djatht").click(function() {
   $("#form3").attr('class',this.id);
});
```

Comment: Instead of using `.click()` and then `unbind`, use [jQuery's `.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Comment: I updated after rereading the question but thanks about the `.one()` reference.

Comment: @Matt LO it did the same job, it added all those classes after clicking them all. but I want to add only one click for each of the IDs, for example if I click the #lart id the lart class will be added, then if I click the #posht id the posht class will be added and the previous class (lart) will be removed

Comment: I updated so it replaces the whole class attribute, try it now.

Comment: @am not i am, updated I guess I had CSS in my mind. small gaffe. thanks

Comment: what if I want it to have two pairs like just to change the lart with posht and majt with djatht, by the way this is the meaning of the ids:
lart=up
posht=down
majt=left
djatht=right

so if I click the up button then I click right the class up with stay its just going to add 1 more class called right, or left!
or if I click the down button then I will can change the right or left but it will be (down and left/right or up and left/right)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you've escaped the quotation marks, but if you only want one class at a time, use...

```
.prop('class', this.id);
```

...instead of `addClass`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `data-` attribute rather than a class name here.

```
$.each(['lart', 'posht', 'djatht', 'majt'], function (idx, id) {
  $('#' + id).click(function () {
    $('#form3').attr('data-selected', id)
  })
})
```

This way, you overwrite the previous value each time you click on one of the triggers. If necessary, you can use the `data-` attribute in CSS selectors:

```
#form3[data-selected="lart"] {
  ...
}
```